# Snap controls to grid?

Tags: ms-office, infopath, infopath-2007, infopath-forms-services

Having just started some work in Infopath after doing a lot of work with .Net Winforms I find manipulating the design of my form a very frustrating experience.

Is there a method, option or addon to have my controls 'snap' into alignment like they do with Visual Studio and some other products?

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: Stackoverflow is for programming related questions. Your question belongs on superuser.com

Comment: Appreciated - will direct my question there.

Comment: superuser is more for admin type questions - almost all application questions (regardless of programming involved) end up over here. you can cross post it but chances are the ops will migrate it back over here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a commenter said - not really. Infopath is a fancy front end for HTML/XML/XSLT so it is more free form than the dev tools you are used to working with. You can tweak layout at a pixel level but as far as alignment your best option is multiple selection and setting location/dimensions manually.